# Installing Caffe framework in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, installation, caffe

I'm currently trying to install the framework Caffe in Ubuntu, following the steps on [this](https://atinesh.medium.com/caffe-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-python-3-6-e76375f0d353) tutorial.

It seems i'm stuck at step 2, where i'm supposed to enable an older version of gcc.

Currently, when i type `gcc -v` on terminal, it throws me this message:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.4.0 20180424 (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1)
```

So i'm assuming the gcc version is indeed 6.4.0

But when I try to build Caffe (Step: 6 of the tutorial) I keep getting the following error:

```
error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 7 are not supported!
```

So, I don't understand.

Either gcc is not the version it throws, or i'm missing something else.

Any hint would be appreciated, I feel really lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to install is via docker, maybe you could refer to Nvidia/caffe forks [here](https://github.com/nvidia/caffe) and the NVCaffe overview [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/caffe-user-guide/index.html).